# !. typescript operator understanding

Tags: typescript, operators

Whenever I use the !. operator with typescript, my compilation errors dissapear, but I searched a bit, and I am not clear what `!.` stands for.

For example, finding a div:

```
let twelveDiv = Array.from(timePickerDivs).find(element => element.innerHTML === '12')
```

This produces a compilation error that makes sense:

```
twelveDiv?.innerHTML = '00'; //The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.ts(2779)
```

However the !. solves it:

```
twelveDiv!.innerHTML = '00'; // no compilation error.
```

Same for a simple class:

```
class MyAwesomeClass {
  private myNumber: number; //Property 'myNumber' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
}
```

In this case both `?.` and `!.` solves the compilation error.

I am familiar with the `?.` for the optional properties and arguments in functions/classes, but not that much with the `!.`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` is the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator). You are telling typescript "i know this looks like it might be null/undefined, but trust me, it's not". This is occasionally needed in cases where typescript can't figure out that your code eliminates the possibility of a null or undefined.

But be aware that like any type assertion, you are telling typescript not to check your work. If you use it, and it actually *can* be null/undefined, typescript will not alert you to this fact, and you'll get an error at runtime.